# Should I avoid to post answer on question going to close?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Consider I visited a question and which looks going to close, Also voted to close, then Should I avoid posting answer to that question?

Example you can see that [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/547786/256099) question is closed (at present on hold) as primarily opinion-based and I also voted to close that but I've also at same time posted [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/547793/256099) (which looks low quality and rater commenting).

I am not particularly asking about my that answer but **in general** (In spite of I can answer a question well,) Should I **avoid** to post an answer while voting to close and also question is about to (going to) close/hold?

Need help for expected behavior from my side.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

As a user of AskUbuntu regulating the site comes first. We should strive to make Ask Ubuntu the "first place to go with no other contestants ever reaching our standards" for anything related to official releases of Ubuntu.

That also includes helping out making life for moderators easy.

That topic to me spells "flamewar" and I would only post there whilst wearing flame retardant clothing.